# error with constructor overload for mocking

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I have 3 assemblies Presenter, Business and DataAccess. Presenter referencing Business and Business referencing DataAccess.

I have a class CustomerBusiness, in Business assembly, with 2 single parameter constructors. The first constructor is used only for testing to mock the data access object. ICustomerDataAccess in DataAccess assembly.

```
    class CustomerBusiness()
    {
      private ICustomerDataAccess _data= null;

      public CustomerBusiness(ICustomerDataAccess data)
      {
        _data = data;
      }

      public CustomerBusiness(string language): this(new CustomerDataAccess("language"))
      {}

      public void SomeOtherMethods()
      {
        ...
      }
    }
```

In the CustomerPresenter class I wrote the code below which gives error that DataAccess assembly is not referened in Presenter. But I don't want to add reference to DataAccess in Presenter.

var custBusiness = new CustomerBusiness("english")

Can anyone recommend what is the best way to implement this, avoiding referencing DataAccess in Presenter?

The error occurs only when there are two single parameters constructors.
The error goes way when I have the below constructors:

```
      public CustomerBusiness(ICustomerDataAccess data, string language)
      {
        _data = data;
      }

       public CustomerBusiness(string language): this(new CustomerDataAccess("language"))
  {}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you move your interface definitions into contract assemblies and have your implementation injected at runtime using an IOC container (like [Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/) but there are many to choose from).

This will break the compile time dependency between the 'implementation' assemblies and negate the need to create separate constructors to pass mocks.

E.G.

```
Presentation  refs  >>  IBusiness(Consumes)
Business      refs  >>  IBusiness(Implements), IDataAccess(Consumes)
IDataAccess   refs  >>  IDataAccess(Implements)
```

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone recommend what is the best way to implement this, avoiding
>   referencing DataAccess in Presenter?

I would suggest either using an IoC container or bubbling your dependencies all the way up to your application root...

You're right - your presenter shouldn't know about your data access class.  But, where you're getting into problematic waters is having your "CustomerBusiness" know about and be responsible for instantiating a data access class.  That first constructor you're using for tests is great -- it's the *only* one you should have.

Then, you should have your Presenter class take a "CustomerBusiness" object in its constructor.  Then, it can use CustomerBusiness without knowing the first thing about how to instantiate it or how to instantiate the data access object, or even about the existence of the data access object.